# Scrape certain links from a page with javascript

Tags: javascript, unique, scrape

**Here is a sample block of code I need to scrape:**

```
<p>This paragraph contains <a href="http://twitter.com/chsweb" data-placement="below" rel="twipsy" target="_blank" data-original-title="Twitter">links to Twitter folks</a>, and <a href="http://twitter.com/blogcycle" data-placement="below" rel="twipsy" target="_blank" data-original-title="Twitter">more links to other Twitter folks</a>, but it also contains <a href="http://www.someOtherWebsiteHere.com">non-Twitter links too</a>.  How can I list only the Twitter links below?</p>
```

**This script generates a list of every URL on the page:**

```
<script>
var allLinks = document.links;
for (var i=0; i<allLinks.length; i++) {
  document.write(allLinks[i].href+"<BR/>");
}
</script>
```

**How do I modify the script so that it only lists URLs that contain a certain domain, e.g.; twitter.com/?**

Here is a demo page:
http://chsweb.me/OucTum

Comment: Beware of `document.write` when you loop DOM node collections, the loop will never get past the first node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On modern browser you could easily retrieve all desired links with

```
var twitter_links = document.querySelectorAll('a[href*="twitter.com"]');
```

using `.querySelectorAll()` is a bit penalizing in terms of speed, but probably you won't notice any significative difference and it will make code easier to read and shorter than using a `for` loop with a regular expression.

Comment: Works beautifully!  Here is the working demo: http://chsweb.me/NCeU6L

Thank you Fabrizio.

Comment: Also, as a follow up, this is only used locally for me to organize links to Twitter folks who commented on a presentation I did.  I am using it to thank them and send goodies; it is not a real life use case, but great that it can be done if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`window.location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.location) properties on the link element to extract different parts of the href. f.ex:

```
var link = allLinks[i];
if ( /twitter\.com/.test( link.hostname ) ) {
    document.write(link.href+"<BR/>");
}
```

Another issue with your code: If you use `document.write` in a for loop, it will effectively empty the collection of links, since they are just a reference to the links present in the current document. So it will never get past the first link. Collect them in an array instead:

```
var links = [];
for (var i=0; i<allLinks.length; i++) {
    var link = allLinks[i];
    if ( /twitter\.com/.test( link.hostname ) ) {
        links.push(link.href);
    }
}

document.write(links.join('<br>'));
```

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/3xub6/

Comment: OK, confirmed, this works too.  Thank you!  There are many similar posts on SO, I hope this helps those folks too.
http://chsweb.me/O2Wtd8

Answer (score 0):

**ORIGINAL:** Not working on demo page ([Sample 6](http://bit.ly/PO2v4o))

```
<script>
if (allLinks[i].href.match("twitter\.com"))
{
     document.write(allLinks[i].href+"<BR/>");
}
</script>
```

**REVISED:** Is working on demo page ([Sample 7](http://chsweb.me/NWHuWi))

```
<script>
var allLinks = document.links;
for (var i=0; i<allLinks.length; i++) {
      if (allLinks[i].href.match("twitter.com")) {
            document.write(allLinks[i].href+"<BR/>");
      }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Hmmm, does not seem to work, here is a demo page that uses the script above for reference: http://chsweb.me/PO2v4o

Comment: Make a jsfiddler out of it instead of trying to host it from Dropbox.

Comment: Here is another take on your approach which does work on the demo page, here: http://chsweb.me/NWHuWi

Answer (score 0):

The following will place all Twitter links in the `twitter_links` array:

```
var twitter_links = [ ],
    links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for(var i in links)
{
    if(/twitter.com/i.exec(links[i].href))
    {
        twitter_links.push(links[i]);
    }
}
```

Here's a jsFiddle for you > http://jsfiddle.net/Pv8DH/

Comment: Confirmed to work - puts links into an alert where they can be copied if needed.  Thank you.